# JPA deceleration exception

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, ejb

I am using jboss5.1.x EJB3.0

I am trying my first time with JPA, and I get this exception when I run the server:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find a persistence unit named 'java:/mracDS'
```

..

this is my "DAO" entity which is responsible on all the JPA entities:

```
  @Stateless
  public class ECMSEntityManagerDao implements ECMSEntityManagerDaoLocal, ECMSEntityManagerDaoRemote
     {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "java:/mracDS")
     EntityManager em;


     public ArrayList<T01CounterCalls> getClocksDetailsFromVantive() throws SQLException
      {
              return (ArrayList<T01CounterCalls>) em.createQuery ("from T01CounterCalls      as data").getResultList ();

       }


     }
```

I looked a bit in the net:
I never declared persistence.xml
and if I do, what should be declared inside?

thanks,
ray.

Comment: Have you already tried Google? http://www.google.nl/search?persistence.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of it my guess is that you are confusing a `persistence unit` with a `data source`.

These two may feel similar, but they aren't. Very simply said a persistence unit is a set of classes plus an associated data source. In the most basic form, a persistence unit merely couples to a data source:

**persistence.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"      
>    
    <persistence-unit name="mracPU">
        <jta-data-source>java:/mracDS</jta-data-source>
    </<persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Then use the persistence unit name with the injection annotations:

```
@Stateless
public class ECMSEntityManagerDao implements ECMSEntityManagerDaoLocal, ECMSEntityManagerDaoRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mracPU")
    EntityManager em;
}
```